# What are the differences between these regex metacharacters?

Tags: javascript, regex

This code

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = "John Smith";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2, $1")
```

and this code

```
var re = /(.+)\s(.+)/;
var str = "John Smith";
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2, $1")
```

does exactly the same thing.

Are there any key differences between  `.` (dot) and `\w`  metacharacters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` matches any non-newline character.

`\w` matches a *word character*, i.e. is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.

Using `\w` might seem the right way to go, but can go a bit wrong when dealing with names, as can be seen here:

```
var str = "Hans-Kristian Whistler";

var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2, $1");
// result: Hans-Whistler, Kristian

var re = /(.+)\s(.+)/;
var newstr = str.replace(re, "$2, $1");
// result: Whistler, Hans-Kristian
```

#### See also:

- [Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) on regular-expressions.info
- [Dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) on regular-expressions.info

Comment: why does it give "Hans-Whistler, Kristian"??

Comment: - is neither alphanumeric nor underscore! Why is it matched??

Comment: @DrStrangeLove - is not matched. It matches `Kristian Whistler` and corrects that, ignoring the `Hans-`-part.

Answer (score 6):

A dot matches every character except for newlines,
`\w` matches all alphanumeric characters, and the underscore (in JavaScript).

So, `.` = `[^\n\r]` , and `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

If you want a literal which matches every character, use:

- `[\S\s]` (all non-whitespace (`\S`) and whitespace (`\s`) characters = all characters)
- `[\D\d]` (all non-digit (`\D`) and all digits (`\d`) characters = all characters)
- `[\W\w]` (all non-word characters and all word characters = all characters)
- etc.

For more information, see [MDN: Regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: @DrStrangeLove No. As far as I know, a newline is not an alphanumeric character or underscore.

Answer (score 1):

`\w` match alphanumeric characters and _ but no whitespaces

```
var re = /(\w+)\s(\w+)/;
var str = "John Herbert Smith";
var newstr = str.replace(re, ">$2<, >$1<");
```

output:

```
>Herbert<, >John< Smith
```

`.` match everything except the linebreak

```
var re = /(.+)\s(.+)/;
var str = "John Herbert Smith";
var newstr = str.replace(re, ">$2<, >$1<");
```

output

```
>Smith<, >John Herbert<
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read about [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) and [`\w`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

About `\w`:

> Matches any alphanumeric character including the underscore. Equivalent to [A-Za-z0-9_].

About `.`:

> Matches any single character except the newline character.